# angular, in Array.map wait for an function end to continue

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I use a tree, and i want to get all the parents of a node.
so i get the list of all my parents and foreach i get the nodes data.

My probleme is, when i iterate on my node ids, I call a function to set datas in my tree (this function will also get the childs). the function get datas from http call.

But in map function i already iterate on the seconde item before the first terminate.

I would like to continue in the map when the first call is finish.

hard to explain i hope it's understandable :)

This is a code example :

```
  setData(parentNode) {
    parentNode.isLoading = true;
    this.dataSource.getData(parentNode.id).subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      parentNode.isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  getData(idToGet) {
    this.data.find(data => data.id);
  }

  initData(){
    const idsToFetch = [1,3,6];
    idsToFetch.map(id => {
      this.setData(
        this.getData(id)
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why don't get the tree structure from the server?

Comment: To much datas :'(